# Running npm script in Dockerfile before dotnet build

Tags: node.js, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I have a .NET Core Web app that I Dockerize for testing. In this app I use webpack and npm Task Runner to automate compiling my SASS files. However, I can't seem to get that working with Dockerfile. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:latest AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:latest AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "Project.csproj"
RUN dotnet build "Project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project.dll"]
```

I've tried both `apt-get` and `FROM node:lts` and running `npm run build`, but neither were successful. Either node would break or `dotnet restore` would. Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:
When I tried `FROM node:lts`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:latest AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM node:lts AS node
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:latest AS build
RUN dotnet restore "Project.csproj"
RUN dotnet build "Project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project.dll"]
```

This gives me the error `package.json not found`. If I specifically put in `COPY package*.json ./` then `dotnet restore` would give an error `Project.csproj not found`.

When I tried `apt-get install`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:latest AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:latest AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN apt-get update -yq 
RUN apt-get install curl gnupg -yq 
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm install
RUN dotnet restore "Project.csproj"
RUN dotnet build "Project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project.dll"]
```

It would say `npm is not a recognized command`.

Comment: what does "break" mean?

Comment: I edited my original post, hope it makes sense!

Comment: is there a package.json in your root dir?  are both package.json and Project.csproj there after the `COPY . .` step?

Comment: I don't know how to check if it got copied to `WORKDIR`, but `package.json` and `Project.csproj` are both in the root directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using multistage build and you just copied in 1 stage not others, that's why 1 or the another stage is breaking. Check the below `Dockerfile`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:latest AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM node:lts AS node
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:latest AS build
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "Project.csproj"
RUN dotnet build "Project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project.dll"]
```

Comment: This might be a dumb question... Would the `COPY` commands not overwrite the contents of each other, making `npm run build` pointless?

Comment: It depends, what are you trying to achieve. I would `COPY` my source code and then do `npm run build` to build the application in the container or another approach, build the application locally and just `COPY` the final artefact in the container.

Comment: npm is supposed to read my `scss` files and write to a `css` file for me. I would need to copy the directory once at the beginning and have Dockerfile run all commands based on that copy.

Comment: Yes, so if you use multistage build, then you need to `COPY` the content again. and if you want to pass content from one stage to another, you can use `COPY --from`

Comment: Unfortunately it's still giving me the same error as above (`Project.csproj does not exist`)

Comment: At what stage you are getting the error? Can you add the output of the docker build in the question?

Comment: `Step 14/21 : RUN dotnet restore "Project.csproj"
 ---> Running in 5acc1df2388d
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: Project.csproj
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "Project.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, I had to manually specify `/src` folder after `from=node`. Thank you for your help!